# hadoop3 can't find .nm-local-dir.usercache.hadoop.appcache. when doing pi test

Tags: hadoop, hadoop3

I'am trying to setup an hadoop3 cluster on a local computer network, in small scale for starting one master node  and two workers node.

I think I manage to have something that should work, following this tutorial [configure hadoop 3.1.0 in multinodes cluster](http://kontext.tech/docs/DataAndBusinessIntelligence/c/hadoop)
I downloaded hadoop version 3.1.1

the dfsadim report:

```
hadoop@######:~/hadoop3/hadoop-3.1.1$ hdfs dfsadmin -report
Configured Capacity: 1845878235136 (1.68 TB)
Present Capacity: 355431677952 (331.02 GB)
DFS Remaining: 355427651584 (331.02 GB)
DFS Used: 4026368 (3.84 MB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
Replicated Blocks:
    Under replicated blocks: 6
    Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
    Missing blocks: 0
    Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
    Pending deletion blocks: 0
Erasure Coded Block Groups: 
    Low redundancy block groups: 0
    Block groups with corrupt internal blocks: 0
    Missing block groups: 0
    Pending deletion blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (2):

Name: ######:9866 (######)
Hostname: ######
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 147511238656 (137.38 GB)
DFS Used: 2150400 (2.05 MB)
Non DFS Used: 46601465856 (43.40 GB)
DFS Remaining: 93390856192 (86.98 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 63.31%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Thu Sep 06 18:44:21 CEST 2018
Last Block Report: Thu Sep 06 18:08:09 CEST 2018
Num of Blocks: 17


Name: ######:9866 (######)
Hostname: ######
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 1698366996480 (1.54 TB)
DFS Used: 1875968 (1.79 MB)
Non DFS Used: 1350032670720 (1.23 TB)
DFS Remaining: 262036795392 (244.04 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 15.43%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Thu Sep 06 18:44:22 CEST 2018
Last Block Report: Thu Sep 06 18:08:10 CEST 2018
Num of Blocks: 12
```

So before continuing and tuning resource management I try to run a simple test and It failed.

here the pi example test

```
hadoop@#####:~/hadoop3/hadoop-3.1.1$ ./bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.1.1.jar pi 2 10
Number of Maps  = 2
Samples per Map = 10
Wrote input for Map #0
Wrote input for Map #1
Starting Job
2018-09-06 18:51:29,277 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at nameMasterhost/IP:8032
2018-09-06 18:51:29,589 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hadoop/.staging/job_1536250099280_0005
2018-09-06 18:51:29,771 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 2
2018-09-06 18:51:30,338 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
2018-09-06 18:51:30,397 INFO Configuration.deprecation: yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
2018-09-06 18:51:30,967 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1536250099280_0005
2018-09-06 18:51:30,970 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2018-09-06 18:51:31,175 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2018-09-06 18:51:31,175 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2018-09-06 18:51:31,248 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1536250099280_0005
2018-09-06 18:51:31,295 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://nameMAster:8088/proxy/application_1536250099280_0005/
2018-09-06 18:51:31,296 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1536250099280_0005
2018-09-06 18:51:44,388 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1536250099280_0005 running in uber mode : false
2018-09-06 18:51:44,390 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2018-09-06 18:51:44,409 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1536250099280_0005 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1536250099280_0005 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1536250099280_0005_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2018-09-06 18:51:38.416]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1536250099280_0005_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Exception message: /bin/mv: target '/nm-local-dir/nmPrivate/application_1536250099280_0005/container_1536250099280_0005_02_000001/container_1536250099280_0005_02_000001.pid' is not a directory


[2018-09-06 18:51:38.421]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class .nm-local-dir.usercache.hadoop.appcache.application_1536250099280_0005.container_1536250099280_0005_02_000001.tmp


[2018-09-06 18:51:38.422]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class .nm-local-dir.usercache.hadoop.appcache.application_1536250099280_0005.container_1536250099280_0005_02_000001.tmp


For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://nameMaster:8088/cluster/app/application_1536250099280_0005 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
2018-09-06 18:51:44,438 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
Job job_1536250099280_0005 failed!
```

I'll add every information asked for, but I don't understand the problem and I don't want to flood the question with all configuration file if their are not relevant.

In the hdfs system file there is no "/nm-local-dir/".
I don't understand from where that path come.

Every help is warmly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

HDFS is storage, YARN is compute.  If you want to use your cluster for anything other than pure storage you'll need YARN which means you'll need Node Managers(NM).

Node Managers are servers that allow you to execute tasks so you need `nm-local-dir` defined in order run jobs like `pi`.  The `nm-local-dir` needs to be defined in yarn-site.xml and is a local directory (not HDFS!) for every host that runs a Node Manager.

Comment: can't access my computer for 2 weeks I test that asap when I am back at the office. but thanks anyways.